# How to use an abstract class as the type of the index variable of a for each loop?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, polymorphism, abstract-class

I was translating a **Java** program of mine to **C++**. I got to a problem trying to use **polymorphism** the same way as in **Java**.

My code looks something like this:

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void print() = 0;
};

class Derived_1 : public Base
{
public:
    void print()
    {
        std::cout << "1" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Derived_2 : public Base
{
public:
    void print()
    {
        std::cout << "2" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

The next are two versions of my main method that I have tried, both give me **compiler errors**:

**1:**

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    std::vector<Base> v;
    
    v.push_back(Derived_1());
    v.push_back(Derived_2());

    for(Base i: v)
    {
        i.print();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Error:**

```
object of abstract class type "Base" is not allowed:C/C++(322)
main.cpp(35, 14): function "Base::print" is a pure virtual function
```

---

**2:**

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    std::vector<Base*> v;
    
    v.push_back(new Derived_1());
    v.push_back(new Derived_2());

    for(Base* i: v)
    {
        i.print();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Error:**

```
expression must have class type but it has type "Base *"C/C++(153)
```

How would you guys solve this?

Comment: `i.` should be `i->`.

Comment: In the first case, see [What is object slicing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing). In the second case, `i` is a pointer, so use `->` instead of `.` to access members. Java doesn't make that distinction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Coming from [java](/questions/tagged/java) to [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), there are a lot to take-care; Especially memory management!

In your first shown case, you are slicing the objects. See [What is object slicing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing)

In order to access the virtual functions, you should have used `std::vector<Base*>` (i.e. vector of pointer to `Base`), or `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>>` or `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base>>`(i.e. vector of smart pointer to `Base`).

In your second shown code, your  `v` is a vector of pointer to `Base`, meaning you need to access the members via the `->` operator.

i.e. You should have accessed the `print()` as follows:

```
i->print();
^^^
```

Or alternatively:

```
(*i).print();
^^^^^
```

---

Also note that:

- In your second case, whatever you `new`ed must be `delete`d, so that the program doesn't leak memory. Alternately, we have [smart memory management](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory)
- The `Base` is missing a `virtual` destructor, which will lead to *undefined behavior* when `delete`ing the ovjects. You should add one for defined behavior. See: [When to use virtual destructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors)

Using `std::unique_ptr`, your code will look like (example code):

```
#include <memory> // std::unique_ptr, std::make_unique

class Base
{
public:
    virtual void print() /* const */ = 0;
    // add a virtual destructor to the Base
    virtual ~Base() = default;
};

class Derived_1 : public Base
{
public:
    void print() override /* const */ {
        std::cout << "1" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Derived_2 : public Base
{
public:
    void print() override /* const */ {
        std::cout << "2" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> v;
    v.reserve(2); // for unwanted re-allocations of memory
    v.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Derived_1>());
    v.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Derived_2>());

    for (const auto& i : v) // auto == std::unique_ptr<Base>
    {
        i->print();
    }
    return 0;
}
```